# bashで一部のsudoコマンドだけ、一般ユーザーでも実行可能にしたい

Tags: macos, bash, sudo

sudoでコマンドを実行させるスクリプトhoge.shを書いています。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/bin/airport
sudo airport sniff 6
```

下記のように他のshから下記のように呼び出したいため、
管理者パスワード入力をせずに「airport sniff」を実行できるようにしたいのですが
方策はございませんでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/
MSG=`hoge.sh`
echo $MSG
```

expectでパスワードをハードコーディングで流し込む方法も考えたのですが
セキュリティ的に躊躇しております。

なお、一般ユーザのままコマンドを実行すると、下記のようなエラーが出ます。

```
$ airport sniff 6
Could not open device en0 (en0: You don't have permission to capture on that device ((cannot open BPF device) /dev/bpf0: Permission denied)).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo`で特定のコマンドをパスワード無しで実行することを許可するには、`/etc/sudoers`に次のように記載してください。

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /pass/to/cmd,/pass/to/cmd
```

usernameはそのまんまユーザー名です。代わりに%groupnameでグループを指定することもできます。
一つ目のALLはホストの制限、二つ目のALLは変身できるユーザーやグループの制限です。より制限を厳しくするにはこれらも設定するとよいでしょう。詳細は`man sudoers`を参照してください。

なお、`/etc/sudoers`は直接編集せずに、

```
$ sudo visudo
```

で編集してください。書式を誤ってもチェックしてくれます。

また、OS Xであればデフォルトで

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

が入ってると思います。これを消さないように。

`/etc/sudoers`の編集を誤ると`sudo`できなくなります。`sudo`できないと`/etc/sudoers`が編集できなくて詰みます。

Answer (score 2):

シェルスクリプト内ではsudoを用いずに実行して、大元のシェルスクリプト本体を実行するときにsudoしたらダメですか？
そういう問題では無い？

---

一応、`sudoers`を編集することでコマンド単位の許可ができます。
自分自身ではやったことは無いので、参考siteを載せておきます。
http://takuya-1st.hatenablog.jp/entry/20090806/1249554458

Comment: 盲点でした。たしかに本体をsudoしておけば、いいのですね。

Answer (score 1):

一般的なコマンドであれば、suidを設定するのがよくされます。

```
chown root:root airport
chmod u+s airport
```

とか・・・
場合によってはセキュリティリスクが生まれるため要注意です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
セキュリティリスクと天秤にはかり、危うそうであれば大元のshをsudoすることにします。